# No array available inside Promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I'm having a stange behaviour (at least for me) using Promise with Javascript on client.

I had a piece of code that was something like this where h is an object:

```
const getSomething = (h) => {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
           //using h (accessing element)
           ....
```

Now the function should accept an array of object but when I use the array inside the promise is `undefined`:

```
const getSomething = (hs) => {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            const a = hs[0] //hs undefined
```

I have tried also something like this:

```
const getSomething = (hs) => {
    const _hs = [];
    _.each(hs, (h) => { h.push(getH(h._id)); }); //where getH return the same object contained in array
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            const a = _hs[0] //_hs undefined
```

I think this could be something memory related, but I have no idea why and what I'm doing wrong.
Any idea?

Comment: hs will never be undefined unless you call `getSomething(undefined)`

Comment: Have you tried just doing `console.log(hs)` before the Promise? Are you modifying `hs` at all before the Promise runs? Remember, it's asynchronous so it won't run until the rest of your running code has come to an end.

Comment: hs it's defined and I can see in it in debug, but not inside Promise

Comment: @perusopersonale Are you sure? Are you also sure that `hs` has a property called `0` or is an array with at least one item in it? If so, then you are definitely mutating the array somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad :) a few lines after I was declaring a variable called hs.

Comment: Whoops! Well, at least you got it figured out!

Comment: Yeah definitely no worries - happens to everyone